# Pagination Database Query Woes

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been working at this all day and still at 8pm have had no luck. I was wondering if you guys can give me some advice on fixing it. I am building an Upload - gif sharing system for University.

Here is my code anyway -

```
 <?php
 ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Top Query");
 mysql_select_db("UPLOAD") or die(mysql_error());   

 $count_query = mysql_query("SELECT NULL FROM details");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($count_query); 

 //pagination 

 if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET['page']);  
 }else{
$page= 1;
 }
 $perPage = 5;
 $lastPage = ceil($count / $perPage);

if($page < 1){
$page = 1;
}else if($page > $lastPage){
$page = $lastPage;
}
$limit = "LIMIT " .($page -1) * $perPage . ", $perPage";

//Query and gifs
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details ORDER BY date_added DESC") or die("2nd Query"); 
//Puts it into an array 


$pagination="";
if($lastPage != 1){

if($page != $lastPage){
    $next = $page + 1;
    $pagination.='<a href="index.php?page='.$next.'">More</a>';
}

if($page != 1){
    $prev = $page - 1;
    $pagination.='<a href="index.php?page='.$prev.'">Back</a>';
}
}
?>
```

And then the output in the html -

```
<?php 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
        $shortlink = "<a href=uploads/".$info['photo'].">".$info['photo']."                   </a>" ;

    //Outputs the image and other data
    echo "<article class='upload-post'>" . "<div class='crop'>";
    echo "<a href=uploads/".$info['photo'].">";
    echo "<img class='scale-with-grid' src=uploads/".$info['photo'] .">"."</a>"; 
    echo "</div>";
    echo "".$info['name'] . "<br/>"; 
    echo "Reaction ".$info['reaction'] ."<br/>";
    echo "In " .$info['category'] ." <br/>";
    echo "On " .$info['date_added'] ." <br/>";
    echo "Link: $shortlink";
    echo "</article>";
 }


?>

 <?php echo $pagination;?>
```

I can toggle between pages but its not limiting the number of posts displayed on the page. Id really appreciate the help as the deadline isn't too far away.
Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: You're setting `$limit`, but you don't seem to be doing anything with it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never append `$limit` to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwing as a replacement...

...

```
//Query and gifs
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details ORDER BY date_added DESC ".$limit) or die("2nd Query"); 
//Puts it into an array
```

...